# Meaning of liquor and leverage

Tags: meaning

Please tell me the meaning of  "liquor and leverage"

Just I read Warren Buffett Ideas there I got this sentence.

> I've seen more people fail because of liquor and leverage.

Comment: I would add the alliterative "loose living" to "liquor" and "leverage" (though loose living tends to be one of the byproducts of hitting the booze):  liquor, leverage, and loose living.  Has a nice ring to it, IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rest of the quote is "You really don't need leverage in this world much. If you're smart, you're going to make a lot of money without borrowing" ([as quoted](http://www.fool.com/investing/general/2014/09/28/25-best-warren-buffett-quotes.aspx))

Liquor, of course, means alcoholic beverages and liquor is a well known path to ruin. Mr. Buffett's point in the quote is about the role of leverage in investing strategy but the alliteration with liquor eloquently pairs these dangerous (in his view) choices.

Leverage in the investing world refers to the lending of money by a brokerage allowing one to trade, and risk, more than they have in their account.  Trading with leverage means your potential gains are larger, but more times than not, it's the larger losses that wipe out a trading account and leave the trader penniless.

His company, Berkshire Hathaway, operates with less debt the other companies. For example, at the time of this post, [BRK-A](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=BRK-A%20Key%20Statistics) has a Debt-To-Equity ratio of 33 compared to 266 at [GE](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=GE%20Key%20Statistics).

Answer (score 2):

I believe Mr. Buffett's use of these terms was a form of [*synecdoche*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/synecdoche?view=uk).  While  alcohol (*liquor*) and borrowed money (*leverage*) have been the specific causes of many a person's downfall, the terms can more broadly refer to vices, especially addictions, and greed (which itself can be an addiction).

The use of a part for the whole, or an example for the general principle, can be an effective literary device, especially when coupled with [*alliteration*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/alliteration?q=alliteration).